Do liquid items stay separate in a Bag of Holding?
I was thinking of playing an Artificer who moonlights as a bartender and I was wondering if I had a Bag of Holding and I poured a bunch of different liquors inside, could I pour them out as individual drinks or would they just mix into the weirdest cocktail ever? Or could I choose either option as a party trick, like take everyone's orders dump everything in the bag at once and then pour out their individual drinks?

Liquids wouldn't stay separate
It's a bag; and normal bags don't keep liquids separate.  The bag of holding has many special properties, keeping liquids separate is not one of them.  Or at least, not one that is described.  Therefore, by RAW, there's no reason to believe the bag keeps liquids separate, so you would just get "the weirdest cocktail ever".
But with the DM's cooperation all things are possible
A cooperative DM might grant you a special "Mixologist's Bag of Holding", or something similar that does what you want, especially since the point seems to be roleplaying, and not gaining some mechanical advantage.  It seems pretty reasonable if the perhaps somewhat whimsical nature of your idea fits the tone of the campaign.
Or even better, maybe the DM can give you an item that just dispenses drinks
You don't really care about the bag of holding aspect of your idea, I think, you care about the drink mixing and dispensing.  The game has plenty of common and uncommon magic items that do simple tricks like that.
Maybe what you need is less a bag of holding and more a "bartender's buddy", something portable that does your mixing and dispensing, and not much else.  That might be easier to sell to a cooperative DM than something that is also a bag of holding.

The alchemist's jug is an item that produces various liquids without having to add them first.  If you're homebrewing an item like this, you might want some of that property as well, like being able to create vodka, gin, wine, simple syrup, orange juice, and other common bases for mixed drinks.  As well as storage for some amount of special liquids that you do have to refill occasionally.

Uncontained liquids are not items
The bag of holding says that:

Retrieving an item from the bag requires an action.

Your question then becomes, if a specific liquid is poured into the bag, is it a discrete item that can be recovered using the bag's property?
Unfortunately, the game does not provide a definition of what constitutes an "item".  It may be related to the definition of 'object', but what the similarities and differences are there is not explicit.
For words without a game definition, we resort to the natural English definition, and it is not a natural usage to include an uncontained liquid as an 'item'.  If I ask you to count 'how many items are on the table?', I would not expect you to include the puddle of water from a spilled drink.
This natural usage is consistent with every one of the 45 examples in the PHB.  By far the most common use of item is as the second half of the phrase 'magic item'.  But the most illustrative use comes from the section on Adventuring Gear (148-153), which is prefaced with:

This section describes items that have special rules or require further explanation.

While several of the entries are of liquids in containers, there are none for uncontained liquids, and the text makes it clear that the item includes the container.  The entry for acid, for example, says:

As an action, you can splash the contents of this vial onto a creature within 5 feet of you or throw the vial up to 20 feet, shattering it on impact.

Note that the item is this vial, while the acid itself is "the contents of this vial".
Suppose I stained several different objects with ink and then put each of them into my bag.  Can I use an action to pull forth "the item that is ink" and thereby remove the stains from each of the different objects?  That is not something I could do without the bag, and I wouldn't expect the bag to somehow be able to do it either.  Magic items do what their descriptions say they do.  The description of the bag merely says that it has the power to make accessible a single item previously placed in the bag.  It does not say that it gives me the power to somehow grab and manipulate an uncontained liquid, an ability that I would not have in the absence of the bag.

I'm not saying you're wrong, but if that's the case, what happens if you just pour a liquid in the bag?

@Eyakos nothing explicitly, meaning some DM interpretation is required based on what they imagine the inside of the bag is like.  Possibly everything inside gets a little bit wet, just as if you had poured the liquid into a mundane 64 cubic foot bag filled with 500 pounds of gear.  Or, if you imagine the inside to be full of compartments, one for each item, then the liquid 'pools' on the bottom of the bag without wetting anything else but only comes out again when you turn it inside out.
